# Stop browser reload of an angular4 application even after changes

Tags: angular, browser

Is there any way we can stop browser reload when we do changes in a live angular4 application. 
So basically what I am looking for is - when you do changes in the angular4 app the browser should render those changes without reloading. So the end user can see the changes live without the page being reloaded.
Also, do we have to build the application every time we make any changes? Is there any way to not build it and get the changes rendered on the DOM.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what kind of changes? If you are talking about code changes, then yes, the components need to be rebuilt in order to recognize the code changes. Or are you talking about data changes?

Comment: Code Changes . @DeborahK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a special tool for it called angular-hmr. you can find it at this link -
 https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angularclass/hmr

after installing it you can write this code in your main.ts:

```
export const hmrBootstrap = (module: any, bootstrap: () => 
 Promise<NgModuleRef<any>>) => {
 let ngModule: NgModuleRef<any>;
   module.hot.accept();
   bootstrap().then(mod => ngModule = mod);
     module.hot.dispose(() => {
     const appRef: ApplicationRef = ngModule.injector.get(ApplicationRef);
     const elements = appRef.components.map(c => c.location.nativeElement);
     const makeVisible = createNewHosts(elements);
     ngModule.destroy();
     makeVisible();
     });
   };
  hmrBootstrap(module, bootstrap);
```

This should replace your

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

The result will be a non flickering updated application after each save. Just dont forget to use it only for development.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am getting error `cannot find name bootstrap` in the `hmrBootstrap(module, bootstrap)`